# How do you replace repetitive text using preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I often have comment forms and lots of users post things such as !!!!!!!!!!! and  ??????????, and I want to use preg_replace to change them to !! and ??, with two maximum.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$t = "aaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccccccc";
$t = preg_replace('~(.)\1{2,}~', '$1$1', $t);
echo $t; // aabbcc
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{2,}`?  Otherwise it would require 4 in a row to trigger (instead of the question's 3 in a row)...

Comment: +1,  I just wanted to make sure I was reading it right (and you weren't taking advantage of something that I didn't understand)...